# Pattern matching for current year and month in filename

Tags: python, file, datetime, directory

I have this initial bit to extract the current month and year value.

The goal is to find (and remove) all files in a log file directory with a name format of 'access.log.2017-11' if the month does not match the current month.

```
log_file_dir = '/home/eos/test/dir'

cur_date = datetime.date.today() 
cur_month = cur_date.strftime('%m') # returns '11', '03'...
cur_year = cur_date.strftime('%Y') # returns 2001, 2017...
```

I tried with glob but it doesn't seem to make a match for what I had in mind likewise:

```
os.chdir(log_file_dir)
glob.glob('./.log.cur_year-cur_month') # nope, not working
```

Is there anywhere that the var names like 'cur_year' can be inserted in a pattern matching expression so that it will find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `'./.log.cur_year-cur_month'` it is considered as a whole string. If you want to use the variables you have to concatenate them with the string and not putting them into quotes : `'./.log.' + cur_year + '-' + cur_month`

Answer (score 1):

```
glob.glob('./.log.cur_year-cur_month')
```

there's no formatting, no string interpolation or any wildcard. It means that glob will look for exactly one file, which is literally `'./.log.cur_year-cur_month'`. This file probably isn't in your folder.

You could use:

```
cur_date.strftime('*.log.%Y-%m')
```

as the [glob pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). It should give you every file ending with `.log.2017-11`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a glob pattern `*.log.2017-11`, this can be created as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import glob

log_file_dir = '/home/eos/test/dir'
log_file_dir = r'e:\python temp'
cur_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m')

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(log_file_dir, '*.log.{}'.format(cur_date))):
    os.remove(filename)
```